# Sampling weights in R

Tags: r, estimation

I am using a dataset (National Longitudinal Survey of Labor Market Experience, 1997 Youth Cohort). The data set contains sampling weights already calculated. How do I incorporate these weights in point estimation in R (e.g., means, proportions etc.)?

Comment: As written, this question doesn't seem to be [on-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CV (we generally don't do "how do I code this in R"). On the other hand, I'm not sure the question is currently suitable for transfer to Stack Overflow (perhaps it would help if it included a code sample, even if it's just an extract from the data frame). It's a nice question, I think ultimately its mostly likely final home is SO.

Answer (score 2):

From the package `survey`, univariate statistics are produced with `svymean` and `svyvar`. You'll need to create a `svydesign` object first.